# AngularJS, where to get data for every input

Tags: angularjs, html, laravel

I built a website, where I have many dynamic elements using AngularJS and Laravel.

For example: I have 3 paragraphs, 1 about, 2 contactus, and 3 phone number

In my database I created a table where I put the description and the value. Example:

```
id   description   value
1    about_text    test1
2    contact_text  test2
3    phone_text     1234
```

I created my query in Laravel and got all the values now. Now I'm getting the response like follows:

`[{description":"about_text","value":test1}....` same for all data.

Now in AngularJS, how can I get the phone text to the phone text.. the contact text to the contact us text. (I defined variables for everything of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are asking for:

```
var text = '[{"description":"about_text","value":"test1"}]';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
var yourvar_description = obj[0].description;
var yourvar_value = obj[0].value ;
```

try and let me know

Comment: Working. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Have a nice day.